# Postgresql: Violates check constraint. Failing row contains

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin, check-constraints

I tried to insert some data in a database with postgresql but still showing the same message:

> ERROR:  new row for relation "empleados" violates check constraint
>   "ck_empleados_documento" DETAIL:  Failing row contains (13, 22222222,
>   f, Lopez, Ana, Colon 123, 1, 2, casado    , 1990-10-10).

I do not know where or what the error is nor did I find anything that solved this. This is what i try to insert:

```
insert into empleados (documento, sexo, apellido, nombre, domicilio, idSecc, cantidadhijos, estadocivil, fechaingreso) values('22222222','f','Lopez','Ana','Colon 123',1,2,'casado','1990-10-10');
```

and this is the structure of the table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.empleados
(
  idempleado integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('empleados_idempleado_seq'::regclass),
  documento character(8),
  sexo character(1),
  apellido character varying(20),
  nombre character varying(20),
  domicilio character varying(30),
  idsecc smallint NOT NULL,
  cantidadhijos smallint,
  estadocivil character(10),
  fechaingreso date,
  CONSTRAINT pk_empleados PRIMARY KEY (idempleado),
  CONSTRAINT fk_empleados_idsecc FOREIGN KEY (idsecc)
      REFERENCES public.puestos (idpuesto) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT uq_empleados_documento UNIQUE (documento),
  CONSTRAINT ck_empleados_documento CHECK (documento ~~ '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'::text),
  CONSTRAINT ck_empleados_estadocivil CHECK (estadocivil = ANY (ARRAY['casado'::bpchar, 'divorciado'::bpchar, 'soltero'::bpchar, 'viudo'::bpchar])),
  CONSTRAINT ck_empleados_hijos CHECK (cantidadhijos >= 0),
  CONSTRAINT ck_empleados_sexo CHECK (sexo = ANY (ARRAY['f'::bpchar, 'm'::bpchar]))
)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error message says your row `violates check constraint "ck_empleados_documento"`.

`ck_empleados_documento` is defined as

```
CONSTRAINT ck_empleados_documento CHECK (documento ~~ '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'::text)
```

According to https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE:

> The operator `~~` is equivalent to `LIKE`

So your constraint really means

```
documento LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'::text
```

From the same page:

> *`string`*`LIKE`*`pattern`*

> If *pattern* does not contain percent signs or underscores, then the pattern only represents the string itself

Your pattern doesn't contain `%` or `_`, so it is equivalent to

```
documento = '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

This can never be true because `documento` is only 8 characters long.

---

You probably want to do this instead:

```
documento SIMILAR TO '[0-9]{8}'
```

[`SIMILAR TO`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-SIMILARTO-REGEXP) uses SQL regexes and understands character classes such as `[0-9]`.

Answer (score 2):

I think your `ck_empleados_documento` should be written like this:

```
CONSTRAINT ck_empleados_documento CHECK (documento ~ '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'::text),
```

Explanation: According to the [Postgres Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-matching.html):

> The operator `~~` is equivalent to `LIKE`

If you want pattern matching you need to use Operators:

```
~       Matches regular expression, case sensitive
~*  Matches regular expression, case insensitive
!~  Does not match regular expression, case sensitive
!~*     Does not match regular expression, case insensitive
```

Comment: Note that `~` does not anchor the match, so it will find any matching substring.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is for those who get this error even when they haven't explicitly defined any constraint. In my case I'm using django and one of my models has a field defined as a `PositiveBigIntegerField`, so the error occurred when some logic tried to set the field's value to a negative number. So check your model/table definitions to make sure you're not violating implicit constraints that exist without your knowledge.